# is it possible to use javascript to change the animation property of a div? on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to create a loading screen that on click it will rotate faster. is it possible to change the specific 2s property to y to accomplish this or do I have to change what I have tried, or is it the `style.animation = "";`. the only thing is that changing the speed in css with animation won't keep the speed cause you can't use `.loading:onclick` it would be `.loading:active` right? so it will only be sped up when I am holding the mouse down so I need a work around either for css or js.

```js
var y = 0.1;

function fast() {
  document.getElementById("a").style.animation = "animateC ys linear infinite";
    document.getElementById("b").style.animation = "animate ys linear infinite";
}
```

```css
body
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background:#262626;
}
.loading
{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:transparent;
  border:3px solid #3c3c3c;
  border-radius:50%;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:150px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff000;
  letter-spacing:4px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-shadow:0 0 10px #fff000;
  box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.loading:before
{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:-3px;
  left:-3px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:3px solid transparent;
  border-top:3px solid #fff000;
  border-right:3px solid #fff000;
  border-radius:50%;
  animation:animateC 2s linear infinite;
}
span
{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 2px);
  left:50%;
  width:50%;
  height:4px;
  background:transparent;
  transform-origin:left;
  animation:animate 2s linear infinite;
}
span:before
{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#fff000;
  top:-6px;
  right:-8px;
  box-shadow:0 0 20px #fff000;
}
@keyframes animateC
{
  0%
  {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%
  {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animate
{
  0%
  {
    transform:rotate(45deg);
  }
  100%
  {
    transform:rotate(405deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<load>
  <div class="loading" id="a" onclick="fast()">Loading<span id=
                                                        "b"></span></div>
</load>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate that you already have an answer but I thought I'd show how one might use Javascript to interact with a [CSS Custom Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) to control the speed of the various elements.
I was just having a play really but it might be useful

```js
const d = document;
const w = window;

const display=()=>{
  console.clear();
  console.log('speed:%s',w.getComputedStyle( d.documentElement ).getPropertyValue('--s'))
};
const clickhandler=()=>{
  let s=parseFloat(w.getComputedStyle( d.documentElement ).getPropertyValue('--s') );
      s-=250;
  if( s > 0 ) d.documentElement.style.setProperty('--s',`${s}ms`);
  display();
};
const changehandler=(e)=>{
  let s=e.target.value;
  if( s > 0 ) d.documentElement.style.setProperty('--s',`${s}ms`);
  display();
};



d.querySelector('.loading').addEventListener('click',clickhandler);
d.querySelector('[type="range"]').addEventListener('change',changehandler);
```

```css
:root{
  /*
    a CSS variable / custom property
    is a great way to apply control
    to the css via Javascript.
    
    A simple variable --s is used for the
    speed, 2000ms = 2s.
  */
  --s: 2000ms;
}
[type='range']{
  width:calc(100% - 2rem);
  height:2px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin:2rem 1rem 0 1rem;
  background:yellow;
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff000;
}
[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  width: 2rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 1rem;
  background: #ffff00;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border:15px ridge gold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff000, 0px 0px 72px 3px rgba(129,214,32,1);
  
}



body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #262626;
}
.loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #3c3c3c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff000;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.loading:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff000;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: animateA var(--s) linear infinite forwards;
}
span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: animateB var(--s) linear infinite forwards;
}
span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff000;
  top: -6px;
  right: -8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff000;
}
/* #a.loading:before */
@keyframes animateA {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/* span#b */
@keyframes animateB {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(405deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading" id='a'>Loading<span id='b'></span></div>
<input type='range' min=100 max=4000 step=50 value=2000>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible - the CSS `animation` property is short hand for multiple properties, amongst which `animation-duration` sets the speed.

Half of the desired outcome can be achieved by setting the `b` element's `style.animationDuration` value to an lesser value:

```js
function fast() {
  document.getElementById("a")
   .style.animation = "animate ys linear infinite";
  document.getElementById("b")
    .style.animationDuration = 500ms; // this works
}
```

Now the bad new: updating the animation duration style property on the "a" element doesn't work at all, possibly because the pseudo element with the transparent border quadrant is the animated element, not the `.loading` element itself. Whatever the reason it didn't work in either Firefox or Edge (a webkit browser  I use for testing).

Looking at the animation code for the `.loading` element made me realise that I personally would start over from scratch, working from the bottom up - with say a single animated element with relative positioning, with either a child element or pseudo element with the colored circle positioned with respect to the border, placed on top of a non animated element containing the "Loading" message and working further up to place that assemblage on the page. If you prefer to  try modifing the posted code to work, more power to you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you set the value of the `animation` property with a string, so just build the string to include the value of your variable.

```js
var y = 0.1;

function fast() {
  document.getElementById("a").style.animation = `animateC ${y}s linear infinite`;
  document.getElementById("b").style.animation = `animate ${y}s linear infinite`;
}
```

```css
body
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background:#262626;
}
.loading
{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:transparent;
  border:3px solid #3c3c3c;
  border-radius:50%;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:150px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff000;
  letter-spacing:4px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-shadow:0 0 10px #fff000;
  box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.loading:before
{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:-3px;
  left:-3px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:3px solid transparent;
  border-top:3px solid #fff000;
  border-right:3px solid #fff000;
  border-radius:50%;
  animation:animateC 2s linear infinite;
}
span
{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 2px);
  left:50%;
  width:50%;
  height:4px;
  background:transparent;
  transform-origin:left;
  animation:animate 2s linear infinite;
}
span:before
{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#fff000;
  top:-6px;
  right:-8px;
  box-shadow:0 0 20px #fff000;
}
@keyframes animateC
{
  0%
  {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%
  {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animate
{
  0%
  {
    transform:rotate(45deg);
  }
  100%
  {
    transform:rotate(405deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading" id="a" onclick="fast()">
  Loading
  <span id="b"></span>
</div>
```